# Listener SelectOneMenu Primefaces is not fired when defaul item is selected

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have a SelectOneMenu like this...

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="somTipoAfectacion" 
                                 value="#{contingenciaBean.ruaAfectacion.idTipoAfectacion}"
                                 required="true" requiredMessage="Campo Requerido"
                                 converter="ruaValorListadoConverter"
                                 valueChangeListener="#{contingenciaBean.listenerSomTipoAfectacion}">
                    <p:ajax event="valueChange" process="@this" update="opTipoRecNatural"/>
                    <f:selectItem value="#{null}" itemLabel="-Seleccione-" itemValue="#{null}"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{contingenciaBean.tipoAfectacionList}" var="taf"
                                   itemLabel="#{taf.valor}" itemValue="#{taf}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

And my Listener is like this..

```
 public void listenerSomTipoAfectacion(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    System.out.println("valueChangeListener() oldValue: " + event.getOldValue());
    System.out.println("valueChangeListener() newValue: " + event.getNewValue());                
}
```

When I select an item from the list...

```
<f:selectItems value="#{contingenciaBean.tipoAfectacionList}" var="taf"
                               itemLabel="#{taf.valor}" itemValue="#{taf}"/>
```

the listener is fired, but when i return to select (click) the default item,

```
 <f:selectItem value="#{null}" itemLabel="-Seleccione-" itemValue="#{null}"/>
```

the listener is not fired. I need that the listener will be fired when i select this default item again.

Thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Can you post your primefaces version / jsf version? ... My listener is fired everytime.

Comment: @pL4Gu33 Primefaces 4.0, JSF 2.1

Comment: i tried it with Primefaces 4.0 and JSF Mojarra 2.1 ... works. Can you post more code with your converter?